# NegativeArraySizeException on a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

For some reason, my program suddenly throws a `NegativeArraySizeException` after running for a while. The code that throws it is behind a command, which I've entered before the exception is thrown.

The code I'm using is mostly for debug purposes, and is the following:

```
final HashMap<String, Integer> busy = new HashMap<>();
//this map gets filled and emptied in threads

System.out.println("Busy tables: " + Arrays.toString(this.busy.keySet().toArray()));
System.out.println("Time busy: " + Arrays.toString(this.busy.values().toArray()));
//map gets read (from the input handler thread)
```

The exception is thrown on the first `System.out.println()` line, but I can imagine it being thrown on the other one too if it'd continued running.

Could it be some sort of Threading issue or could the cause be somewhere else?

Google gave me (for the first time in ages) no usable results. How can a Set have a negative size anyway?

Edit: The exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at nl.lolmewn.statsglobal.Main.handleInput(Main.java:61)
    at nl.lolmewn.statsglobal.Main.access$000(Main.java:20)
    at nl.lolmewn.statsglobal.Main$1.run(Main.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the version of Java you are using.

Comment: make a `System.out.println(busy.keySet().size())`

Comment: You are not modifying the `HashMap` or its key set in multiple threads without proper locking, are you? Because that would certainly create a lot of *interesting* side-effects...

Comment: maybe KeySet() returns -1

Comment: @ALJIMohamed Certainly not. keySet() returns a Set. Sets can't be -1.

Comment: Instead of 'Arrays.toString(this.busy.keySet().toArray())' you could just write 'busy.keySet()'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without more information about your code, I would consider unprotected multi-threaded accesses to the `HashMap` object to be the prime suspect. [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), contrary to [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), is *not* synchronized and needs explicit locks to work in a multi-threaded environment, either directly or through the sets returned via `keySet()` or `entrySet()`.

Failing to do that can create a lot of *interesting* side-effects due to the `HashMap` being in a inconsistent internal state. I would suggest using a debugger to break on that exception and have a better look at what is going on.

Comment: As an addition to this answer: The exception in this case would be caused when the `toArray()` method tries to allocate an array of the appropriate size using `HashMap.size()`. But `HashMap.size()` is based off of a size field which gets updated on puts and removes. As such, in a multithreaded environment one can get more (partially) successful removes than puts and with this a negative size field.

Comment: Changing the HashMap to a ConcurrentHashMap fixed the issue. Multi-threads on a normal HashMap is pretty interesting indeed after all :)