# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException with WeakHashMap keySet

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
 public synchronized static ArrayList<HttpSession> getCurrentSessionList() {
      return new ArrayList<HttpSession>(sessions.keySet());
   }
```

We have a client who is getting a `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` where the list is initialised with the values of the keys from the Map `sessions`. I am unable to replicate it. They are using OpenJDK 7 build 71, on Linux.

`sessions` is a WeakHashMap which I assume is what is causing the issue. I understand that creating a new List will create a hard-reference to the items in the Maps, but this is short lived and only used for reporting on the contents of the Map.

The reason the ArrayList is created is so that items can be manipulated in loops etc., without having to worry about items in the WeakHashMap disappearing.

Can anyone suggest a safe way of initialising this list?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104897/negativearraysizeexception-on-a-hashmap

Comment: No, I hadn't.. And I understand that this is happening because the Map is concurrently modified. I can't replace a WeakHashMap with ConcurrentHashMap implementation though... I am unable to determine from the Java Doc as to whether the using a synchronizedMap will stop concurrent modifications by the garbage collector.

Comment: Search the internet for WeakConcurrentHashMap...

Comment: Why do you even *have* the `WeakHashMap`? If you have data that is keyed by the session, why isn't it *in* the session?

Comment: @EJP, the Map is a link to all sessions within the application. We use it for listing users currently logged in, and for limiting each username to one concurrent session. The application adds and removes sessions explicitly from this map using session listeners, but it was implemented as a WeakHashMap as a failsafe that if the session was not explicitly removed that the session would be removed from the list when it was destroyed.. maybe this is over-engineered and should just be a standard map as I can't think of a reason the session listener wouldn't be called to remove it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `sessions` is a synchronized map backed by a `WeakHashMap`.

The [JavaDoc for the ArrayList constructor being invoked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) says:

> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, *in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator*.

(Emphasis added.) Therefore, this constructor iterates over the given collection.

The [JavaDoc for Collections.synchronizedMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-) includes this very important note:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:
>
> ```
> Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
>     ...
> Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
>     ...
> synchronized (m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
>     Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

If `sessions` is indeed a synchronized map, then `new ArrayList<HttpSession>(sessions.keySet())` is non-deterministic. You need to synchronize on `sessions`:

```
public synchronized static ArrayList<HttpSession> getCurrentSessionList() {
    final Set<HttpSession> keys = sessions.keySet();
    synchronized (sessions) {
        return new ArrayList<HttpSession>(keys);
    }
}
```

.. and the getCurrentSessionList() static method probably does not need to be itself synchronized.